# Adaptive processes using rules

Tags: drools, jbpm

In jBPM, if we create a process with a rule task and then deploy the process. During process execution, before the rule task is executed, I have changed the business logic in the DRL file and saved it. But this change is not reflected in the currently running instance. Is this correct behavior for an adaptive process?

Comment: Not an expert, but I guess that you have to re-deploy the file. Probably jBPM is not monitoring changes to your file system.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the business logic in your DRL file, you should release new deploy version in order to mantain your process execution, so changes are reflected in new process instances and old process instances mantain the rules defined when it started